# libGDX: Change the color of a PNG according to user's input

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, game-engine

i hope you can help me.
I have a game where transparent textures are loaded and should be colored according to the user's choice (HEX code) at the beginning of the game.

My game has tiles where the gameFigures will be placed (centered).
Tiles are 50x50 are so is my png. it has a transparent background and the vector of my Figure has transparent stuff that should be colored.
It looks something like this:

[image]

I am using libGDX engine, and i am really frustrated because of this problem.
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks alot!

Comment: Updated my answer showing how input can affect the render loop (in this case changing the color of an image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change colors programmatically in LibGDX you need to use an image (png or jpg) with **white pixels** you can achieve this effect splitting your image in 2 parts, one for the part that you don't want the color to be changed and one for the parts that you do.
Here's an example:

[image: Example color]

Code:

```
public class ExampleGame extends InputAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Color crownColor;

    public ExampleGame() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        crownColor = Color.WHITE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        crownColor = Color.RED;
        return false;
    }

    public void render(TextureRegion player, TextureRegion crown) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Else player will be affected by crownColor too
        batch.draw(player, 0, 0);
        batch.setColor(crownColor);
        batch.draw(crown, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!
and sorry for my late reply.
i have two problems, the first is that my game has more that 12 players which is going to make it very difficult to have 24 .png files and move them the whole time around.. :/
the second is that the SpriteBatch is drawing every thing after i call the method setColor() with the same color chosen before. is there any way to reset the color of the SpriteBatch please?
thanks again!

Comment: It's gonna be a "pain in the ass" moving 24 png around and add listeners to them, etc..
Do you have any other idea please?

Comment: never mind reseting the color of the SpriteBatch, i've done it using the setColor(new Color(1,1,1,1))

Comment: You could also have your own Player class with position (A Vector2) and a render method so in your render method you make a loop of all the players calling their render() method

Comment: Oh that's right!!
i am really grateful for your help!